# PHP MySQL count events per location per user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a query using data from 4 tables: Bookings, Users, Events, Locations

**Bookings** :

```
+---------------------------------+
|book_id   | event_id | person_id |
+---------------------------------+
|1         | 1        | 2         |
|2         | 2        | 1         |
|3         | 2        | 2         |
|4         | 1        | 3         |
|5         | 3        | 1         |
|6         | 3        | 2         |
+---------------------------------+
```

**Users** :

```
+----------------------+
| user_id  | name      |
+----------------------+
| 1        | Joe       |
| 2        | Jack      |
| 3        | Jane      |
+----------------------+
```

**Events** :

```
+------------------------+
| event_id | location_id |
+------------------------+
| 1        | 1           |
| 2        | 3           |
| 3        | 1           |
+------------------------+
```

**Locations** :

```
+---------------------------+
| location_id | name        |
+---------------------------+
| 1           | Lombard     |
| 2           | NYC         |
| 3           | LA          |
+---------------------------+
```

The query that I can't seem to write should get me to display a table like this :

```
+------------------------------+
+Name     |Lombard|NYC|LA|Total|
+------------------------------+
+Joe      |1      |0  |1 |2    |
+Jack     |2      |0  |1 |3    |
+Jane     |1      |0  |0 |1    |
+------------------------------+
+Totals   |4      |0  |2 |6    |
+------------------------------+
```

What I got to work is displaying how many booking have been made per user but not per user AND per location using this query:

```
$query='
SELECT
bookings.person_id,
COUNT(bookings.person_id) AS total,
bookings.event_id,
users.display_name

FROM bookings

INNER JOIN users ON bookings.person_id=users.id
WHERE users.id=bookings.person_id

GROUP BY bookings.person_id';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 /* total bookings per user */
 $value = $row['total'];
 $sum += $value;

 /* Displaying results */
  echo "<tr width='500'>";
    echo "<td>".$row['person_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['display_name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['total']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

This works okay and displays :

```
 +-----------------------------------+
 | ID    |  NAME   | Total Bookings  |
 +-----------------------------------+
 | 7     |  Bob    | 3               |
 | 5     |  Jane   | 2               |
 | 3     |  Joe    | 1               |
 +-----------------------------------+
```

Could you please help me getting there. Thanks.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: you need `group by user, location`. you're grouping on user only.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to do a pivot table to get the results you need

Comment: @Jay all excellent points.  Could `mysqli` be used as an alternative to `PDO`?  It has been a while but I remember it being pretty straightforward to port my application from `mysql` to `mysqli`.

Comment: Yes @steveklein you can use `mysqli` as an alternative to `PDO`. No matter which you choose you need to use parametrized queries.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll learn about prepared statements and PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a pivot table style query. Here's one way you can do it.

```
select u.name, 
       count(case when l.name = 'Lombard' then 1 end) as lombard,
       count(case when l.name = 'NYC' then 1 end) as nyc, 
       count(case when l.name = 'LA' then 1 end) la, 
       count(u.name) total
  from bookings b
    inner join events e
      on b.event_id = e.event_id
    inner join locations l
      on e.location_id = l.location_id
    inner join users u
      on u.user_id = b.person_id
  group by u.name
  with rollup
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c1e7/6)

It gets a lot harder (and is generally easier to do in the application) if you dont know the possible column (location) values when you are writing the query.

Comment: thank you very much pala_. The pivot table query works great.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92d50

```
  SELECT u.name, 
       SUM(l.name = 'Lombard') lombard,
       SUM(l.name = 'NYC') nyc, 
       SUM(l.name = 'LA') la, 
       COUNT(*) total
  FROM bookings b
  LEFT JOIN `events` e
    ON b.event_id = e.event_id
  LEFT JOIN locations l
    ON e.location_id = l.location_id
  LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = b.person_id
  GROUP BY u.name
  WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: thank you very much Alex. Your pivot table query works great too.